# How to fill the image 100% inside a button

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

It should be simple but somehow I am getting problems to do it in a more generic way (without width and height properties).

I have a button and an image inside this button but when I insert an image I see the it is not 100% filled.

[image]

This is my code:

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
        Style="{StaticResource BrowseButtonStyle}" 
        Click="ChangeLogo_Click">

    <Image x:Name="imageControl" />
</Button>
```

How can I fill it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go take a look at a copy of the [default Button template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj709909.aspx) you'll see the `ContentPresenter` has its `Margin` Template bound via a `Setter` with a "Padding" of 12,4 by default.

So easiest answer, just specify a zero padding.

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
        Style="{StaticResource BrowseButtonStyle}" 
        Click="ChangeLogo_Click" 
        Padding="0">
    <Image x:Name="imageControl" />
</Button>
```

Hope this helps.